# Copy unmatched strings in from one file to another, bulk

Tags: command-line, bash, files

I'm trying to compare files from `folder1` to their updated version in `folder2`. The files have identical names, but may have different number of strings. The strings look like:

```
string_1_name: "some text"
string_2_name: "some text"
.
.
string_n_name: "some text"
```

So I need to compare only the parts of the strings before colon - `string_1_name`, and then if a file1.txt from folder2 has an extra or updated string, I want to copy the full string `string_1_name: "some text"` and paste it into the `file1.txt` from `folder1` but in the same location (an updated string can be in-between old strings) or replace an old string with an updated one. And then create the result `file1.txt` (with the same name) in `folder3`.

It will be great if the newly added strings in the result files were highlighted some how, colored or at least bolded.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show an example of a filename in folder1 and its correspondent in folder2, as per how written it's hard to understand. I guess you meant " I need to compare only the parts of the strings *after* colon"?

Comment: Not exactly, I don't care about "some text", I just care about the first part of a string, before the colon divider. 
Example of a string:
`noas_no_fort: "Without a fort, there is nothing to assault."`

The text in quotes in file1.txt will be in different language, but the name of a localisation will be in both cases in english.

Comment: Also, the strings are divided by 'Carriage returns'.

Comment: The filenames will be identical in both folders, ex.: `file_1_english.txt`.
In folder2 `file_1_english.txt` may contain more strings than same file from folder1.

Answer (score 1):

try `diff -u file_1.txt file_2.txt > patch1o2`
then `patch -p0 < patch1o2`

the first command will create a file called `patch1o2` containing all the difference between the two files
The second command will add in the first file the content of the difference at the same line position.

output will be a file_1.txt updated with extra lines from file_2.txt

edit 14/07/2015 :
create a bash script with a loop to analyse all files present in folder
here are an example:

```
FILE_1=folder_1/*.txt
for i in "$FILE_1"
do  
    awk -F"," '{print $1}' "$i"
done
```

Comment: That will work if I wanted to compare a whole file, but I need to compare just the names of the strings, if there are any new strings added. And then copy that added (whole) string to the original file.

Comment: then make a diff only on column1 with somethinf like `awk -F ":" '{print $1}'`

Comment: How about doing it for all files in those folders?

Comment: one thing that I don't understand, why `diff -u [...]` followed with `patch _p0` is not OK.   its mean that you could have the same first column in the two files with only the second one which differ ?

Comment: Because in this case the second column in file_1.txt gets replaced by the second column in file_2.txt

Comment: To clarify: 1) I need to check if the second file has any new strings and if it does, add them to the first file (and for that your solution is perfect). 2) But, the first file will have column_2 translated to a different language, though column_2 from the second file will replace it with English translation, which is unacceptable.

Comment: UPD: OK, one step at a time. I managed to get the first column extracted:
`awk '{print $1 > "file1_col1.txt"}' file1.txt `
Now how do I apply use this command for all files in a specific folder?
Also I want the destination file name will be generated like this  InputFileName_col1.txt

Comment: see answer above, I updated it with a small loop inside a bash script

Comment: This script 
`FILE_1=~/Dropbox/113_eng/*.txt 

for i in "$FILE_1" 

do 

awk -F";" '{print $1 > "~/Dropbox/113_res/*.txt"}' "$i" 
done`

Gives me error:

`awk: can't open file /Users/billy/Dropbox/113_eng/*.txt
 source line number 1`
Apologies for the formatting @green-frog

Comment: you have an error with redirection `> "~/Dropbox/113_res/*.txt"}` you cannot note redirect in *.txt you need to redirect to someting like `$i.new`